# “Life is too short to regret of …”

Tags: grammar, clauses

> Life is too short to regret of not “living your dreams” that ultimately “make your life”.

Is this sentence correct, or does it require corrections?

Comment: I wonder if the author (after removing the incorrect “of”) understands the meaning: We should live our dreams, but if we don’t then we shouldn’t regret it because life is too short to waste time on such regrets. I’ll try to remember that, but I won’t be too sad if I forget it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it presented in one sentence only, I would write it as:

> Life is too short to regret not living your dreams because it is your dreams that make your life.

Not sure why you are using the quotes for "living your dreams" or "make your life." You would normally use quotes for quoted speech. Sometimes people use them to show sarcasm or irony, also called Apologetic Quotations, but good writing usually doesn't need the emphasis of quotations to convey intent.

Comment: In your final sentence, are you referring to [scare quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes)?

Comment: I agree that the quotes are not needed around _living your dreams_ (that's an established enough idiom). As for the second pair, I don't think those are needed, either; moreover, if I were to leave them in, I might move them: _it is your dreams that ultimately "make" your life._

Answer (score 1):

You do not "regret of" something, you simply "regret" it. So you should write, "Life is too short to regret not living your dreams."

Ditto Charlotte on wondering why you include the quotes. Taking the sentence by itself, the quotes should not be included. Maybe in context there is some reason for them.